# multiple tables join by Linq

Tags: linq, join, left-join

I have 3 tables which named Player, PlayerDetails and Team. I want to write a linq statement such as

```
from p in Player join d in PlayerDetails on p.ID equals d.PID
```

and then right join team table, Player has a column named TID which face to Team table's ID.

I have tried to write a statement like

```
from p in Player join d in PlayerDetails on p.ID equals d.PID into PlayerGroup
from t in team join g in PlayerGroup on t.ID equals g.p.ID
```

It certainly can't work. I'm not sure how to write such type of query statement, table left join table2 then right join table3.

Who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
var LeftJoin =
    from p in Player
    join d in PlayerDetails on p.ID equals d.PID into pd
    from d in pd.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        pID = p.ID,
        pTID = p.TID,
        dID = d.ID
    };

var RightJoin =
    from t in Team
    join l in LeftJoin on t.ID equals l.pTID into tl
    from l in tl.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        tID = t.ID,
        pID = l.pID,
        pTID = l.PTID,
        dID = l.dID
    };
```

To do everything in one query, I think you could do (not tested) something like this:

```
var RightJoin =
    from t in Team
    join l in
        (from p in Player
         join d in PlayerDetails on p.ID equals d.PID into pd
         from d in pd.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new
         {
             pID = p.ID,
             pTID = p.TID,
             dID = d.ID
         })
    on t.ID equals l.pTID into tl
    from l in tl.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        tID = t.ID,
        pID = l.pID,
        pTID = l.PTID,
        dID = l.dID
    };
```

Comment: Hi Ole_Brun, thanks for your reply. I know it certainly works well, but, could I write one statement instead of two?